# Screen Saver nor Sleep Mode working on my Lenovo Yoga, Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep, screensaver, lenovo-laptop

My screen saver nor sleep mode ever kick on.  I have windows 8.1 and a Lenovo Yoga.  I have the setting enabled for both to kick on after few minutes to test and nothing ever happens.  I've read a few posts but nothing is working.  The Troubleshooting is not finding anything.  Thanks for any help can provide.

Comment: Install your graphics driver, that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check all device drivers are installed. Install them all. Then try to disable screensaver and enable it again. Should work in most cases.